# How to set boundaries for turtles to not go through?

Tags: python, boundary, topdown

I am programming a top down shooting game sort of like Hotline Miami and I have every thing sorted but the only problem is.

That I can't find a way for the "bad people" to not go though the walls of the map, I need some help setting up boundaries.

Comment: What have you tried? Please share your code.

Comment: Read from [how-do-i-have-an-object-rebound-off-the-canvas-border](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51793908/how-do-i-have-an-object-rebound-off-the-canvas-border/51810173#51810173) the `def bounce(...` function.